# Topological structure/graph from a paper

Tags: general-topology, ordinary-differential-equations, graph-theory

This question is based off a paper titled "On designing heteroclinic networks from graphs." I'm having a difficult time visualizing something "drawn in 4-dimensions" projected down to a 2-dimensional graph $G$. This is an excerpt from the paper:

[image]

Basically the idea is you have a sequence of equilibria $\xi_1, ..., \xi_4$ and orbits that connect them in a sequence. What I'm struggling with is taking their image in Figure 3 and projecting it down to what a 4-vertex graph should look like. I'm also not understanding what $p$ is supposed to represent. It seems like they're making it a parameter but I don't understand the point of it. Can anyone please help me visualize this? I would like to be able to take a graph and project it to a network, but I need to understand how to go back and forth between them.

Answer (score 1):

That image looks a lot like a [book embedding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Book_embedding) of a graph. To project the book embedding onto the plane, you have to choose for each edge whether it should go above or below the central axis - assuming that is the axis is drawn horizontally.

Comment: Ah interesting. I have never heard of a book embedding, so perhaps their structure is just an extension of that. How does one choose whether each edge should go above or below the central axis?

Comment: I don't know of an algorithm to choose a planar embedding of a book embedding such that there are minimal crossings. I've drawn a lot of these 'linear' graphs in the plane, but it's never been important for me to have the least number of crossings - or, in general, make some algorithmic choice of which side of the axis to use. Basically, it's just a case of what looks nicest!